# Nested keys in a dictionary concatenation of arrays

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

I have a large multi level key dictionary as:

```
mydict = {}
mydict['a1'] = {}
mydict['a1']['b1'] = {}
mydict['a1']['b1']['c1'] = np.array([1,2,3])
mydict['a1']['b1']['c2'] = np.array([11,21,31])

mydict['a2'] = {}
mydict['a2']['b1'] = {}
mydict['a2']['b1']['c1'] = np.array([1,22,3])
mydict['a2']['b1']['c2'] = np.array([61,2,453])
```

I want to concatenate all the arrays stored in the dictioary. For a single level I can use `numpy.concatenate` and concatenate on dictionary `values()`. How do I extract all arrays stored at the deeper level and concatenate them? The arrays are of same size.

Edit 1: 
concatenation order doesn't matter.

Edit 2
concatenation in a single array.

Comment: Problem is seriously underspecified and lacks a proper example that I can paste into my interpreter.

Comment: added a paste version

Comment: Are all your arrays always at the same level in `mydict`?

Comment: Great, now we need the desired output. Does concatenation order matter?

Comment: concatenate in a single array or a list of arrays?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, here's a solution using recursion on the dict and flatten method of np.ndarray (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html):

```
def concat_last_level(inp):
    # we are at the bottom of the dictionary: return the array
    if isinstance(inp, np.ndarray):
        return inp
    # recursive call
    if isinstance(inp, dict):     
       return [concat_last_level(el) for key, el in inp.iteritems()] 

np.array(concat_last_level(mydict)).flatten()   

# array([ 11,  21,  31,   1,   2,   3,  61,   2, 453,   1,  22,   3])
```

This can be generalised in many ways, but really depends on your problem.
Also, if you are using Python 3.x, use inp.items() in the function./